# Fatal error: Call to a member function save_file_info() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ERP/application/controllers/demo2.php on line 82

Tags: model-view-controller

I am a new PHP developer, I have been working sample codeigniter program file upload.
File upload successfully in the folder, but error was coming. How to resolve..
**Controller** // There were errors, we have to delete the uploaded files

```
 if ($is_file_error) {
                if ($file) {
                    $file = './uploads/' . $file['file_name'];
                    if (file_exists($file)) {
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!$is_file_error) {
                //save the file info in the database
                $resp = $this->file->save_file_info($file);
                if ($resp === TRUE) {
                    $this->handle_success('File was successfully uploaded.');
                } else {
                    //if file info save in database was not successful then delete from the destination folder
                    $file = './upload/' . $file['file_name'];
                    if (file_exists($file)) {
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                    $this->handle_error('Error while saving file info to Database.');
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is  error your getting

Comment: Check your file path `./uploads/` is correct

Comment: please post the entire controller function

Answer (score 0):

Your $this->file does not contains object of file, put this in if condition and then call save_file_info($file) on it.

```
if( $this->file )
{
    $resp = $this->file->save_file_info($file);
}
else
{
    $this->handle_error('File is not uploaded properly!, please try again.');
}
```